# updating odoo database backend doesn't reflect

Tags: database, postgresql, orm, migration, odoo

Dears,

I had to update odoo database (postgresql 12) by a script using the psql utility, and script run successfully.

But I couldn't find the added tables in Models and of course the added module not showing even after upgrading all modules and restarting the service.

Any ideas how to enforce odoo to detect database schema changes.

Thanks,

Comment: Instead of updating external data into odoo's database directly, I would advice you use 
 odoo external API for that. They are easy to use and pretty straightforward once you get the hang of it. Here is a link to its documentation [web_services]https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/webservices/odoo.html) .This is useful since odoo will handle updating data to its tables itself

Comment: I'm familiar with external APIs, but I think it's for CRUD of fields inside tables already exist. But in my case, I'm trying to create new tables.

Comment: Every time you run the script a new table should be created?

Comment: Yes, I'm running script creates tables for module, instead of installing it from the frontend, but it didn't reflect. Then, how to enforce this reverse action on ORM ?!